# Restructure an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array in PHP

```
$fields = array(
    0 => array(
        'field1' => 'something1',
        'field2' => 'something2'
   )
)
```

And I need it to look like this

```
$fields = array(
   'fields1' => 'something1',
   'fields2' => 'something2'
)
```

What function code can I use to get rid of the 0 index in the example?

Comment: What about if `$fields` array has more than 1 element?

Comment: Making example 1 look like example 2 doesn't really tell us what your end-goal is, do you need to plan for many elements or do you just need the first element?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through like this...

Create new array

```
$newArray = [];
```

Then loop through

```
foreach($fields as $field){

    if(is_array($field)){        
       foreach($field as $key => $value){
           $newArray[$key] = $value;
       }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array, loop through $fields, and merge whatever items are there with the created array.

```
$final_array = array();

foreach ($fields as $field)
{
    $final_array = array_merge($final_array, $field);
}

$fields = $final_array;
```

This will be able to handle any number of items in either level of the array and compact them into a one-level array.

Answer (score 0):

just take the '0' element from fields:

```
$fields=$fields[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
      $fields = reset($fields);
```

Or

```
       $fields = array_shift($fields);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($data)); $list = iterator_to_array($it,false);
```

Use this to get ride of any extra levels. 
Will gives you what you want